# "Out of memory" on Chrome - selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium

When I run my script, which uses a Chrome Webdriver, I find that after around the 1400th execution of a function, an `Out Of Memory` error happens. What the function does is basically does is load an image or upload some text.

The error is simply solved by pressing the ***Enter Key*** once the message is displayed. Of course, that is an unwated solution since it defeats the purpose of selenium automatization.

What I've tried so far is to re-load the page every 400th execution of the function to see if I could somehow reset the stack. That somewhy doesn't work.